# How to find the text which is outside of a tag using selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, tags

I want to retrieve all anchor tags which are labeled as "Working" from the following code.

```
    <div class="A">
         <a href="facebook.com">Profile 1</a>
         Working
         <br/>
         <a href="gmail.com">Profile 2</a>
         <br/>
         <a href="linkedin.com">Profile 3</a>
         Working
         <br/>
   </div>
```

Here I want to retrieve the anchor tags of "facebook" and "linkedin" as they have labeled as "Working".

Following are my trails which didn't work properly.

```
//div[@class='A']//a//following-sibling::text()
//div[@class='A'][contains(text(),'Working')]
```

Could any one provide the xpath to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below expression:

```
//div[@class='A']/text()[normalize-space()="Working"]/preceding-sibling::a[1]
```

Which returns

```
<a href="facebook.com">Profile 1</a>
<a href="linkedin.com">Profile 3</a>
```

Comment: It won't work if you want text node as output, but this expression returns `WebElement`, so it's ok

Comment: Hey Kudos Andersson...It's working fine.. I never come across this "normalize-space()". From where can I learn these?. Please suggest me more techniques on these type of xpaths. Do you have any reference?

Comment: @RaakiGadde, you can check [this](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf) to learn how to create good `XPath` expressions and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions) you can find `XPath` functions list